# How to connect manually using Multipeer Connectivity (swift)

Tags: swift, multipeer-connectivity

Im creating `P2P` chat iOS application (swift).

I want to save the peer obj which have connected once to `userDefault` and connect without inviting when connecting the peer next time.

I think using the func

```
session.connectPeer(peerID: MCPeerID, withNearbyConnectionData: NSData)
```

is solve my requirement, however I cant understand how to use this method, especially `withNearbyConnectionData` arg.

Comment: Thank you for your editing alex_p :)

Comment: I want to know how to save session and restore it without inviting, like Line (once allow to join the group(session) and create group, never ask join or not when returning the room of it).